# Antd: How to change tooltip label on table sorter

Tags: javascript, antd

I'm new using `Antd`, I've create a table with sort functionalities, but I need to change the text on the tooltip of the sorter.

Sorter tooltip:-

[image]

Thanks in advance, if you need any extra code snippet just please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
<Table showSorterTooltip={{ title: 'Clic para ordenar' }}
       columns={tableColumn}
       dataSource={item}
       rowClassName='ps-pointer'
       rowKey={record => record.codigo_pedido_compra}
       style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
  />
```

The trick is to use the showSorterTooltip property.

Comment: The problem with this is that regardless of the column, the text is always the same. Say I hover over a sorted column (asc). The default behaviour is to display 'Click to sort descending' however over a different, not sorted, column 'Click to sort ascending' will be displayed. Using `showSorterTooltip` there's no notion of the sort state of the column you're hovering over. This is a problem if all you want to do is change props like `color`, `placement` or even `destroyTooltipOnHide`...

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/25791) issue in github you can set `locale` property of Table to what you want

```js
<Table 
      locale={{ 
          triggerDesc: 'descend sort text',
          triggerAsc: 'ascend sort text', 
          cancelSort: 'cancel sort text'
      }}
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, tables use the Sorter object, which implements a Tooltip.

You can find more information on the Table API here: https://ant.design/components/table/

And more on the Tooltip API here: https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#API

Essentially you'll want to set the yourTable.showSorterTooltip property to an object which contains the properties you want. It looks like the specific property you're looking for is just "title" but you can see the full list of properties in the Tooltip API

Comment: Thanks. According to the documentation, I have to set showSorterTooltip to my object with the properties, like this: showSorterToolTip={{title:'new text'}}.
But the text of the label doesn't change.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have an extra pair of curly braces. It should read more like this:

yourTable.showSorterToolTip = {title: 'new text'}

Comment: The documentation says that you can either pass a boolean value which will set whether or not the tooltip is visible at all, OR you can pass an object with the Tooltip API's properties set.

Comment: @Step how did you solve that, could you please share?

Comment: @hasany review my answer.

Comment: @Step As you commented first, it doesn't change the tooltip title at my trial too, by providing showSorterToolTip={{title:'new text'}}. Are you now able to change the tooltip title by giving like that?

Comment: @hasany is showSorterTooltip, with the "t" of "tip" lower. 
Maybe it's that.

Comment: @Step I see your previous problem now. Actually it was with small t that I try, it's big since I just copied from your previous comment. Althoughs I'm trying exactly this:
`showSorterTooltip={{title: 'test'}}` it still shows "Click to sort ascending" title.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same sorter message everywhere then you can just do:

```
<Table showSorterTooltip={true} />
```

or

```
<Table showSorterTooltip={{title: 'Sorter Title'}} />
```

but if you want to have different sorter message for different sort state in individual column ( when sort type is multiple ) then what you can do is:

- maintain the sort state for the columns
- Update the sort title as per the sort state in the column (ColumnType also has showSorterTooltip):
- showSorterTooltip: {{title: 'Individual title'}}