# Change tooltip text according to order in showSorterTooltip

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, antd

I want to change the text of the tooltip according to the order. It is possible to change text using locale props in the table as is mentioned [here]([Antd: How to change tooltip label on table sorter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698838/antd-how-to-change-tooltip-label-on-table-sorter). I, however, also need to change the style of the tooltip so I have used the showSorterTooltip in the column instead

```
{
      title: 'Student name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      sorter: (a: any, b: any) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name),
      render: val => val,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.includes(value),
      showSorterTooltip: {
        title: <span className="sort-tooltip-background"> Click to sort </span>,
        placement: 'topRight',
        arrowPointAtCenter: false,
        autoAdjustOverflow: true,
        align: { offset: [20, 0] },
        color: '#fff'
      },
      width: '14vw'
    },
```

How do I change the title according to the order as is the default behaviour in sorting table in antd? Thank you in advance

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  locale={{
        triggerDesc: 'Click to sort descending',
        triggerAsc: 'Click to sort ascending',
        cancelSort: 'Click to cancel sorting'
      }}
/>
```

This works but I cannot change the placement of the tooltip without using showSorterTooltip property.